# Compress and merge multiple JS files using Shrinksafe

Tags: javascript, dojo, compression

I need to compress and merge multiple JavaScript files (in a particular folder) to a single file using Shrinksafe. I'm able to merge the files to a single one using the below command.

```
java -jar shrinksafe.jar  *.js  >  testMin.js
```

The problem with this is that, it does not put all the script in a single line. It just removes the comments.

Also I need to achieve the same task using ant build script.

I tried the below approach

```
<target name="compress-js">
    <echo message="Starting JS compress Build"/>            
    <java fork="true" dir="${shrinksafe.util.path}/buildscripts" classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main">
         <arg value="build.js"/>
         <arg line="releaseDir=../../../../../../StaticFiles/acb profile=acb_js action=clean,release *.js > acb.js" />
         <classpath>
           <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/js.jar"/>
           <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar"/>
           <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
         </classpath>
   </java>
   <echo message="js build successfull." />
</target>
```

I'm not sure if I can achieve my requirement using the above script. The is the dojo profile that I'm using.

```
//Below code is from acb-js.profile.js file.
    dependencies = {
            layers: [      
                {
                    name: "../gp-js.js",
                    resourceName:"gp-js",
                    dependencies: [
                    ]
                }
            ],
            prefixes: [
              ["scripts", "../../scripts"]
            ]
    };
```

My JavaScript files are inside `StaticFiles/acb/homepage` folder.

Please help me.Thanks in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the online facility for ShrinkSafe [Here](http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/)? I haven't used the jar or ant to do that, so I don't know how if that will work!